# Create NSString by repeating another string a given number of times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string

This should be easy, but I'm having a hard time finding the easiest solution.

I need an `NSString` that is equal to another string concatenated with itself a given number of times.

For a better explanation, consider the following python example:

```
>> original = "abc"
"abc"
>> times = 2
2
>> result = original * times
"abcabc"
```

Any hints?

---

EDIT:

I was going to post a solution similar to the one by [Mike McMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260945/create-nsstring-by-repeating-another-string-a-given-number-of-times#260969), after looking at this implementation from the OmniFrameworks:

```
// returns a string consisting of 'aLenght' spaces
+ (NSString *)spacesOfLength:(unsigned int)aLength;
{
static NSMutableString *spaces = nil;
static NSLock *spacesLock;
static unsigned int spacesLength;

if (!spaces) {
spaces = [@"                " mutableCopy];
spacesLength = [spaces length];
    spacesLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
}
if (spacesLength < aLength) {
    [spacesLock lock];
    while (spacesLength < aLength) {
        [spaces appendString:spaces];
        spacesLength += spacesLength;
    }
    [spacesLock unlock];
}
return [spaces substringToIndex:aLength];
}
```

Code reproduced from the file:

```
Frameworks/OmniFoundation/OpenStepExtensions.subproj/NSString-OFExtensions.m
```

on the OpenExtensions framework from the [Omni Frameworks](http://www.omnigroup.com/developer/) by [The Omni Group](http://www.omnigroup.com/).

Answer (score 168, accepted):

There is a method called `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:`:

```
[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:100 withString: @"abc" startingAtIndex:0]
```

Note that if you want 3 abc's, than use 9 (`3 * [@"abc" length]`) or create category like this:

```
@interface NSString (Repeat)

- (NSString *)repeatTimes:(NSUInteger)times;

@end

@implementation NSString (Repeat)

- (NSString *)repeatTimes:(NSUInteger)times {
  return [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:times * [self length] withString:self startingAtIndex:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: +1 for doing it all in a single call to the standard library. And here's how I used it to create a comma-separated list of question marks (for feeding to SQLite) -- `[@"" stringByPaddingToLength:[fields count]*2-1 withString:@"?," startingAtIndex:0]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *original = @"abc";
int times = 2;

// Capacity does not limit the length, it's just an initial capacity
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[original length] * times]; 

int i;
for (i = 0; i < times; i++)
    [result appendString:original];

NSLog(@"result: %@", result); // prints "abcabc"
```

Comment: I was trying to come up with something simpler, but I think this is the shortest way.

Comment: I made it a little more efficient since the acceptance by specifiying times first and having the capacity = [original length] * times

Comment: Just for completeness, if for some reason you want to use large numbers, you can improve this by reusing power-of-two concatenations (e.g. foo * 10 = foo * 2 + foo * 8; foo * 8 = foo * 4 + foo * 4; foo * 4 = foo * 2 + foo * 2 -> 3 concat operations instead of 9).

Comment: This solution is not as efficient as top answer using `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:`

Answer (score 4):

For performance, you could drop into C with something like this:

```
+ (NSString*)stringWithRepeatCharacter:(char)character times:(unsigned int)repetitions;
{
    char repeatString[repetitions + 1];
    memset(repeatString, character, repetitions);

    // Set terminating null
    repeatString[repetitions] = 0;

    return [NSString stringWithCString:repeatString];
}
```

This could be written as a category extension on the NSString class. There are probably some checks that should be thrown in there, but this is the straight forward gist of it.

Comment: Great idea, specially for performance hungry scenarios. Thanks!

Comment: David, repetitions is an unsigned int

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out `NSString`'s `stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:` is implemented in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The first method above is for a single character. This one is for a string of characters. It could be used for a single character too but has more overhead.

```
+ (NSString*)stringWithRepeatString:(char*)characters times:(unsigned int)repetitions;
{
    unsigned int stringLength = strlen(characters);
    unsigned int repeatStringLength = stringLength * repetitions + 1;

    char repeatString[repeatStringLength];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
        unsigned int pointerPosition = i * repetitions;
        memcpy(repeatString + pointerPosition, characters, stringLength);       
    }

    // Set terminating null
    repeatString[repeatStringLength - 1] = 0;

    return [NSString stringWithCString:repeatString];
}
```

Comment: There's an error, I think, inside the for cycle:  
`unsigned int pointerPosition = i * repetitions;`  
should be  
`unsigned int pointerPosition = i * stringLength;`  
where  
**i * repetitions**  
becomes  
**i * stringLength**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cocoa in Python, then you can just do that, as PyObjC imbues `NSString` with all of the Python `unicode` class's abilities.

Otherwise, there are two ways.

One is to create an array with the same string in it `n` times, and use `componentsJoinedByString:`. Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *repetitions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];
for (NSUInteger i = 0UL; i < n; ++i)
    [repetitions addObject:inputString];
outputString = [repetitions componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

The other way would be to start with an empty `NSMutableString` and append the string to it `n` times, like this:

```
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[inputString length] * n];
for (NSUInteger i = 0UL; i < n; ++i)
    [temp appendString:inputString];
outputString = [NSString stringWithString:temp];
```

You may be able to cut out the `stringWithString:` call if it's OK for you to return a mutable string here. Otherwise, you probably  should return an immutable string, and the `stringWithString:` message here means you have two copies of the string in memory.

Therefore, I recommend the `componentsJoinedByString:` solution.

[Edit: Borrowed idea to use `…WithCapacity:` methods from [Mike McMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260945/create-nsstring-by-repeating-another-string-a-given-number-of-times#260969).]

Comment: Thanks for the alternative of using componentsJoinedByString.

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion. Probably a teeny bit more efficient that my (admittedly generic) solution.