# Java String Multiplication

Tags: java, python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I multiply strings in java to repeat sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255500/can-i-multiply-strings-in-java-to-repeat-sequences)

In Python, we can easily multiply the stings.

```
count = 10
print '*' * count
```

Is there any similar option available in Java?

Comment: what is the result of string multiplication in python??

Comment: It successively concatenates the string.  e.g. >>> 'a' * 10
'aaaaaaaaaa'

Comment: see my answer and let me know if this is what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this??

`System.out.println(String.format("%10s", "").replace(' ', '*'));`

This gives me output as `**********`.

I believe this is what you want...

### Update 1

```
int yournumber = 10;
System.out.println(String.format("%" + yournumber + "s","*").replace(' ', '*'));
```

### Good Luck!!!

Comment: Can we give the runtime value instead of 10?

Comment: Ofcourse: `int n = 10; System.out.println(String.format("%" + n + "s", "").replace(' ', '*'));`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Dollar](https://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/wiki/Home) for your purposes(Java API that unifies collections, arrays, iterators/iterable, and char sequences.)

```
String str = $("*").repeat(count);
```

In this way you will get result `"**********"` as you want.

Java doesn't have that feature for now.

Comment: what does this statement do actually?? what is the end result in `str`??

Comment: you have said `Java doesn't have that future for now`. Does this mean it has been deprecated??

Comment: No, Java is very powerful language. I just says that there isn't any operator ibuilt-in Java to multiply strings.
Of course, you can use StringBuilder and via for cycle multiply it and then bring it back to it, but I will prefer to use simple API and get that future's to my program.

Comment: By [future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future) do you mean [feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature)?

Comment: Oh sorry, just misspelling :D

Comment: I hear you.  I use a spell checker, but that would not have picked up that mistake, since what you typed was the correct spelling for a different word.  Good edit.  +1  :)

Comment: @mesiesta : check my answer :D one liner, sweet and short like you...

Answer (score 6):

```
char[10] c = new char[10];
Arrays.fill(c, '*');
String str = new String(c);
```

To avoid creating a new String everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that in Java is to use a for() loop:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s += "*";
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: I would prefer mesiesta answer over you...

Comment: It makes everytime new string, because strings are immutable in Java. I will suggest to use Dollar or use StringBuilder class instead of String.

Comment: @mesiesta you're right that a new `String` is created every time but not because the immutability of `String`. Rather because each iteration creates a _different_ `String` than the previous ones. E.g. one-star, two-stars, three-stars, etc.

Comment: This is an abominable solution. Seriously. @yair you're definitely wrong here. It creates a new string because they're immutable and s cannot be appended to it must get recreated. In fact all string modifications require recreating the string because they are immutable.

Comment: @anon58192932 reading this more than 7 years later, this is a somewhat philosophical  argument, what is the exact cause for the creation of new strings every iteration. `s += "*"` is syntactic sugar of `s = s + "*"`. AFAIR, the runtime first executes `s + "*"`, which is done regardless of the assignment. The result is first assigned to a new address, not `s`'s. Then `s` is assigned that new address. So, in this regard, the immutability of strings is not the cause for creating new strings. The cause is just the order of instructions execution.

Comment: @anon58192932 it's agreed that the solution is not ideal, but please avoid using unpleasant words like "abominable".

Comment: it's the truth. never shy away from the truth. abominable: very bad or unpleasant. This solution is both of those and should be deleted.