# How to print a char a certain number of times?

Tags: java

I am trying to create code that takes a user-inputted number, and store it as an int. I then print out 'int' number of lines, with 'int' number of 'char' in each of them. So say for example, the inputted number was 3, it would then output

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

However, when I try to do this, it just gives me the number it would calculate of the ASCII number * the inputted number. This is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
    int number = kb.nextInt();
    kb.close();
    char letter = 'X';
    int sqnumber = number * number;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println (letter * number);
    }
}
```

However, this just gives me:

```
Please enter a number:
3
264
264
264
```

Comment: The line `System.out.println (letter * number);` prints 88 * 3, being 88 the ASCII value of X.

What is the point of this line?: `int sqnumber = number * number;`

Comment: Checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255500/can-i-multiply-strings-in-java-to-repeat-sequences  The first answer may be helpful to you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have nested for loops and you are not using char `X`correctly.

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        int number = kb.nextInt();
        kb.close();
        char letter = 'X';
        int sqnumber = number * number;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
                System.out.print(letter);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Output

```
Please enter a number:
4
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. It prints out the Xs straight going down.

Comment: its a working example.You are messing something else.

Comment: You are welcome.I dont understand why down vote.Care to comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is `repeat()` method in String object(Appeared in Java 11). Example:

```
System.out.print("XXX\n".repeat(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
        System.out.print(letter + "");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

char is an integral type in Java. So you are multiplying ASCII value of 'X' with 3 each time. Edit your loop to -

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            System.out.print(letter);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you probably want something like this:

```
private static void printSquare(int size) {
    char[] line = new char[size];
    Arrays.fill(line, 'X');
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        System.out.println(line);
}
```