# Trigger dependent jobs in Multibranch Pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Multibranch Pipeline projects to build my applications. We have around 100+ components and those many pipeline projects. So say for e.g. we have:

Project `A` dependent on →  Project `B` dependent on → Project `C`

We are using SCM polling for all these jobs. I want that once I build Project `C`, Project `B` should be built and after that Project `A` should be built. My list of dependencies can vary from project to project.

I know that a Maven project can handle this with *Build Triggers* → ☑ *Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built*, but with Multibranch Pipeline plugin, did not find any way to handle this.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

There is ☐ *Build after other projects are built* in the branches' configuration pages and it can be selected but the branches' configurations cannot be saved (The menu item in the branches' side bar reads just *View Configuration*, not *Configure*).

The following as `Jenkinsfile` should do what you're trying to achieve. Add it to all of your branches. In case of changes edit it on your `master`/`trunk` and  cherrypick it to branches that are affected by these changes.

```groovy
// From: Trigger dependent jobs in Multibranch Pipeline project
//       http://stackoverflow.com/a/38151703/1744774

String[][] buildChains = [
  ['master'],
  ['branch1', 'master'],
  ['branch2', 'branch1', 'master'],
  ['no-build']
  // ... further build chains ...
  ]

for ( buildChain in buildChains ) {
  if ( buildChain[0].equalsIgnoreCase( env.BRANCH_NAME ) ) {
    int depth = 0
    for ( branch in buildChain ) {
      String depthIndicator = "+" * ++depth
      //optional: String depthIndicator = new String(new char[++depth]).replace('\0', '+')
      //optional: String depthIndicator = repeat( "+", ++depth )
      println "  $depthIndicator Triggering build for branch '$branch'"
      build( branch )
      } // for ( branches )
    break // comment this if there are more build chains for one branch
    }
  } // for ( buildChains )


def build( String branch ) {

  switch ( branch ) {
    case "master":
      buildMaster()
      break
    case ["branch1", "branch2"]:
      buildBranch( branch )
      break
 // case ...
 //   ...

    default:
      println "  --- No build defined for branch \'$branch\' ---"
    }  // switch ( branch )
  }  // build( branch )

def buildMaster()   {
  println '  Building branch \'master\'...'
  // ... build code ...
  }

def buildBranch( String branch )    {
  println "  Building branch '$branch'..."
  // ... build code ...
  }

// From: Can I multiply strings in Java to repeat sequences?
//       http://stackoverflow.com/a/34650746/1744774
String repeat( String s, int count ) {
  return count > 0 ? s + repeat( s, --count ) : ""
  }
```

Running it on `branch1`:

```
[Pipeline] echo
  + Triggering build for branch 'branch1'
[Pipeline] echo
  Building branch 'branch1'...
[Pipeline] echo
  ++ Triggering build for branch 'master'
[Pipeline] echo
  Building branch 'master'...
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Running it on `branch2`:

```
[Pipeline] echo
  + Triggering build for branch 'branch2'
[Pipeline] echo
  Building branch 'branch2'...
[Pipeline] echo
  ++ Triggering build for branch 'branch1'
[Pipeline] echo
  Building branch 'branch1'...
[Pipeline] echo
  +++ Triggering build for branch 'master'
[Pipeline] echo
  Building branch 'master'...
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Remember to approve initially prohibited functions with the [Script Security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin) under *Manage Jenkins* → *In-process Script Approval*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try it out.

Comment: @SarojGharat You're welcome. If you want to thank people here on SO see [Why is voting important?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: I had to use full path to trigger successfully