# string based on int value

Tags: java, integer, while-loop

what I am looking to do here is create a string based on the value of an int.

I know I am able to create a vale of an in based on a sting via the `length()` method but was wondering how to do the opposite.

for example I have an int of 30, with that int I would like to create 30 dots ina line based on that int and place it in a println

```
 {


     while (wordlegnth1 + wordlegnth2 < LINELENGTH)

     {

         dots++;
         wordlegnth1++;

     }

     System.out.println (word1 + dots + word2);
   }
```

at the moment, al the println does is prints the 2 words entered, the int value based on the 2 words entered eg stack24overflow

basically what I would like to do is change that 24 from an int into 24 dots (........................)

many thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Padding Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/padding-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of wanting to [repeat a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java) (or a character, for that matter) some number of times.

However, there's a simple solution of just looping to output a period `dots` number of times and printing that directly to the screen:

```
System.out.print(word1);
for(int d = 0; d < dots; d++){
    System.out.print(".");
}
System.out.println(word2);
```

Alternatively you can form a string (using `StringBuilder`) first and then output it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(dots);
for(int d = 0; d < dots; d++){
    sb.append('.');
}
System.out.println(word1 + sb + word2);
```

Note that the `StringBuilder`'s capacity is initialized to `dots`.

Comment: That doesn't actually create a string of dots instead it just would print a bunch of them.

Comment: @zobgib: the OP didn't ask to create a string of periods, rather, to output the number of periods corresponding to `dots`, that's what this does, and all it claims to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

Here's a cheap and simple one, albeit not very general:

```
    static final String manyDots = "...........................................";
    ...
    dots = manyDots.substring(0, nosDots);  // if nosDots <= manyDots.length()
```

Here's a more general version:

```
    char[] dotChars = new char[nosDots];
    Arrays.fill(dotChars, '.');    
    dots = new String(dotChars);
```

... which is more or less equivalent to:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(nosDots);
    for (int i = 0; i < nosDots; i++) {
        sb.append('.');
    }
    dots = sb.toString();
```

The Apache Commons [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class has various methods for this kind of thing; e.g. `leftPad`, `rightPad`, `center` and `repeat`.  Calling `StringUtils.repeat(".", nosDots)` would do exactly what you are trying to do.

Finally, the `String.format()` method and the `Formatter` classes do this kind of thing, in a higher level way.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x - 30;
String dots = "";
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
     dots += "."; 
}
System.out.println(dots);
```

What I am doing is taking the int value and looping that many times.  The then `+=` operator concatenates the dots variable.  So for instance  `"." + "." = ".."`

Comment: String concatenation in a loop is inefficient.

Comment: True.  It creates (and then discards) a StringBuilder under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] letters = new char[ 30 ];
Arrays.fill(letters, '.');
String s = new String( letters );

System.out.println( s );
```