# for loop print - as many as the word length?

Tags: java, string

How can I print out dashes "-" in the same length as the word length?
I used for-loop but only got 1 dash.

```
    for(int i=0; i<secretWordLen; i++) theOutput = "-";
```

Main:

```
public String processInput(String theInput) {
    String theOutput = null;

    String str1 = new String(words[currentJoke]);
    int secretWordLen = str1.length();

    if (state == WAITING) {
        theOutput = "Connection established.. Want to play a game? 1. (yes/no)";
        state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
    } else if (state == SENTKNOCKKNOCK) {
        if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            //theOutput = clues[currentJoke];
            //theOutput = words[currentJoke];
            for(int i=0; i<secretWordLen; i++) theOutput = "-";
            state = SENTCLUE;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107297/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-generate-a-string-of-n-repeated-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<secretWordLen; i++) {
    builder.append('-');
}
theOutput = builder.toString();
```

This will do if all you want in `theOutput` is the series of dashes. If you want to have something before, just use builder.append() before appending the dashes.

The solution with `+=` would work too (but needs `theOutput` to be initialized to something before, of course, so you don't append to `null`). Behind the scenes, Java will transform any `+=` instruction into a code that uses `StringBuilder`. Using it directly makes it more clear what is happening, is more efficient in this case, and is in general a good thing to learn about how String are manipulated in Java.

Comment: Thanks, yup the `+=` solution will append null as you mentioned if not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your output-variable in each iteration.

Change it to:

```
theOutput += "-";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `theOutput = "-";` use `theOutput += "-";`

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the result each time.

```
for(int i=0; i<secretWordLen; i++)
 theOutput += "-";
```

When you write    `theOutput += "-";`  that's the shorthand of

```
   theOutput = theOutput +"-";
```