# Webdriver simplest way to enter a longstring with sendKeys?

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver

I want to add about 1000 or 10000 repeating letters/words to a textarea with:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("message")).sendKeys("asdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasd");
```

I haven't found a proper example how to achieve this.

Comment: Use RandomStringUtils package to generate a string. Then send it via sendKeys(randomString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a string to pass to `sendKeys`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
while (sb.length() < 1000) {
  sb.append("sequencetorepeat");
}
webElement.sendKeys(sb.toString());
```

There are [more efficient ways to repeat strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107297/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-generate-a-string-of-n-repeated-characters), but this is a simple approach for reasonably short strings.