# Java: String - add character n-times

Tags: java, string

Is there a simple way to add a character or another String n-times to an existing String?
I couldn’t find anything in `String`, `Stringbuilder`, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with a `for` loop?

Comment: Are you looking for one method? there isn't one.

Comment: **I couldn´t find anything in String, Stringbuilder** ... I'm sure you haven't seen `append(str)` method of `StringBuilder` or `+` concat operation of `String`.

Comment: Yes for one or a chain of mehtods, I´d like to avoid the loop ;)

Comment: Any method you use will use a loop for you. You can write such a a method of your own.

Comment: Sure it uses a loop, but I don`t create my own methods if there are already some.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are able to do this using Java 8 stream APIs. The following code creates the string `"cccc"` from `"c"`:

```
String s = "c";
int n = 4;
String sRepeated = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> s).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Answer (score 50):

Apache `commons-lang3` has [`StringUtils.repeat(String, int)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat(java.lang.String,%20int)), with this one you can do (for simplicity, not with `StringBuilder`):

```
String original;
original = original + StringUtils.repeat("x", n);
```

Since it is open source, you can read how it is written. There is a minor optimalization for small n-s if I remember correctly, but most of the time it uses `StringBuilder`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/59087

Answer (score 46):

In case of Java 8 you can do:

```
int n = 4;
String existing = "...";
String result = existing + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, "*"));
```

Output:

```
...****
```

In Java 8 the `String.join` method was added. But `Collections.nCopies` is even in Java 5.

Comment: Gotta love single-line solutions. +1

Answer (score 32):

For the case of repeating a single character (not a String), you could use [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29):

```
  String original = "original ";
  char c = 'c';
  int number = 9;

  char[] repeat = new char[number];
  Arrays.fill(repeat, c);
  original += new String(repeat);
```

Comment: This might be one of the most efficient ways and can still be written in three lines.

Answer (score 16):

Use this:

```
String input = "original";
String newStr = "new"; //new string to be added
int n = 10 // no of times we want to add
input = input + new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", newStr);
```

Comment: I am sure the "`"-Symbol is not right at the end of line 4... ;)

Comment: Why the `new char[n]`? Shouldn't it be `new char[n*newStr.length()]`?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Strings.repeat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method:

```
String existingString = ...
existingString += Strings.repeat("foo", n);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    existing_string += 'c';
}
```

but you should use StringBuilder instead, and save memory

```
int n = 3;
String existing_string = "string";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(existing_string);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    builder.append(" append ");
}

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 5):

Its better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` because String is an immutable class and it cannot be modified once created: in String each concatenation results in creating a new instance of the String class with the modified string.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, you should initialize the `StringBuilder` with an appropriate capacity, especially that you already know it. For example:

```
int capacity = existingString.length() + n * appendableString.length();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(capacity);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String appendNewStringToExisting(String exisitingString, String newString, int number) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(exisitingString);
    for(int iDx = 0; iDx < number; iDx++){
        builder.append(newString);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't mean to have "existingString" in quotes.  Right?  You meant to pass the argument in there.

Comment: yeah, without IDE sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 String toAdd = "toAdd";
 StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
 for(int count = 0; count < MAX; count++) {
     s.append(toAdd);
  }
  String output = s.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if the "n" is large, it might not be such a great idea to use +=, since every time you add another String through +=, the JVM will create a brand new object (plenty of info on this around).

Something like:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(existing_string);
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    b.append("other_string");
}
return b.toString();
```

Not actually coding this in an IDE, so minor flaws may occur, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: you mean this is more efficient?

Comment: Yes, it is much more efficient for operations where you do many appends to the original String, or simply when you're building a String through the concatenation of several sub-strings. http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/strings/23stringbufferetc.html read the bit on efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it:

```
final int numberOfSpaces = 22;
final char[] spaceArray = new char[numberOfSpaces];
Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');
```

Now add it to your `StringBuilder`

```
stringBuilder.append(spaceArray);
```

or `String`

```
final String spaces = String.valueOf(spaceArray);
```

Comment: That’s quite similar to sudocodes answer.

Answer (score 0):

To have an idea of the speed penalty, I have tested two versions, one with Array.fill and one with StringBuilder.

```
public static String repeat(char what, int howmany) {
    char[] chars = new char[howmany];
    Arrays.fill(chars, what);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

and

```
public static String repeatSB(char what, int howmany) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(howmany);
    for (int i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
        out.append(what);
    return out.toString();
}
```

using

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String res;
    long time;

    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        res = repeat(' ', 100000);
        res = repeatSB(' ', 100000);
    }
    time = System.nanoTime();
    res = repeat(' ', 100000);
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println("elapsed repeat: " + time);

    time = System.nanoTime();
    res = repeatSB(' ', 100000);
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println("elapsed repeatSB: " + time);
}
```

(note the loop in main function is to kick in JIT)

The results are as follows:

```
elapsed repeat: 65899
elapsed repeatSB: 305171
```

It is a *huge* difference

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple way..

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  yourString = yourString + "what you want to append continiously";
}
```

Comment: You should use StringBuilder in a loop, because string concatenation in a loop is O(xn^2)