# Expand the tabs in Java

Tags: java, string, whitespace

Do you know a java method to expand the  chars of a text into spaces?

My text:

```
1. <tab>  firstpoint  <tab> page  1
10. <tab> secondpoint <tab> page 10
```

If I directly replace the tab by, let say, 4 spaces, I will have

```
1.    firstpoint    page1
10.    secondpoint    page2
```

Instead of it, I need a method to replace each tab by the number of spaces it really corresponds to (as the command :retab of vim does). Any solution?

Comment: For searchabilities sake: what you want are [tab stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there's probably a library out there that does this, the manual solution is quite simple:

1. Create an output buffer (`StringBuilder`).
2. Iterate through the string's characters
3. For each character check if it's a tab or not.
   a. If it's not a tab, add it to the output buffer.
   b. If it's a tab, add a space first, then as many spaces as it takes for the length of the output buffer to be divisible by 4. (Your tab length.)
4. Return the output buffer.

Answer (score 5):

I think there might be an issue with the retab() function above ignoring an initial tab. I made my own; hereby placed into public domain.

```
public static String expandTabs(String s, int tabSize) {
    if (s == null) return null;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '\n' :
                col = 0;
                buf.append(c);
                break;
            case '\t' :
                buf.append(spaces(tabSize - col % tabSize));
                col += tabSize - col % tabSize;
                break;
            default :
                col++;
                buf.append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

public static String spaces(int n) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int sp = 0; sp < n; sp++) buf.append(" ");
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think it's missing `col += tabSize - col % tabSize;` in the `'\t'` case.

Comment: Great answer - a few suggestions:

* Split if statements into two lines so you can set break points on the body 

* Take advantage of StringBuffers capacity constructor and give it help to pre allocate storage.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any implementation on the web, so I have written it myself, on the idea of biziclop:

```
/**
 * Replace the tabulator characters of a String by the corresponding number of spaces.
 * Example:<pre>
 *   1.&lt;tab&gt;firstpoint&lt;tab&gt;page  1
 *   10.&lt;tab&gt;secondpoint&lt;tab&gt;page 10 </pre>
 * will become<pre>
 *   1.      firstpoint      page  1
 *   10.     secondpoint     page 10</pre>
 *
 * @param text     the text
 * @param tabstop  the espacement between the tab stops, typically 4 or 8
 * @return The text, with no &lt;tab&gt; character anymore
 */
public static String retab(final String text, final int tabstop)
{
    final char[] input = text.toCharArray();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int linepos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<input.length; i++)
    {
        // treat the character
        final char ch = input[i];
        if (ch == '\t')
        {
            // expand the tab
            do
            {
                sb.append(' ');
                linepos++;
            } while (linepos % tabstop != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(ch);
            linepos++;
        }

        // end of line. Reset the lineposition to zero.
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || (ch|1) == '\u2029' || ch == '\u0085')
            linepos = 0;

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'd definitely replace that `char [] output` with `StringBuilder output`.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote [The ANTLR Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933524/2147204) using Java 8 Streams, also using [Alexis C.'s Streams-based code to repeat a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27690536/2147204):

```
static String repeatString(String s, int count) {
   return Stream.generate(() -> s).limit(count).collect(Collectors.joining());
}

static String expandTabs(String s, int tabSize) {
   int[] col = new int[1];
   return s.chars().mapToObj(c -> {
      switch (c) {
         case '\t':
            int expandBy = tabSize - col[0] % tabSize;
            col[0] += expandBy;
            return repeatString(" ", expandBy);
         case '\n':
            col[0] = 0;
            break;
         default:
            col[0]++;
      }
      return String.valueOf((char) c);
   }).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Eldar (Abusalimov,  Terence Parr) post.

Changes:

1. Split if-statements onto two lines so you can set break points on body

2. Use StringBuffer's capacity constructor to help it pre-allocate storage.

```
public static String expandTabs(String str, int tabSize) {
    if (str == null)
        return null;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length()+tabSize);
    int col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
            case '\n' :
                col = 0;
                buf.append(c);
                break;
            case '\t' :
                buf.append(spaces(tabSize - col % tabSize));
                col += tabSize - col % tabSize;
                break;
            default :
                col++;
                buf.append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return buf.toString();
}

public static StringBuilder spaces(int n) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(n);
    for (int sp = 0; sp < n; sp++)
        buf.append(" ");
    return buf;
}
```