# How can I make a function that prints a string indentend?

Tags: java

A method called printIndented() that takes a String, an integer and a boolean. The
integer represents the size of an indentation from the left margin in spaces, so the
method should first p
rint that many spaces. Then the string should be printed.
Then, if the boolean is true, a newline should be printed. So for example,
`printIndented(3, "Hello", false)`
would print:

```
˽˽˽
Hello
...with no newline at the end.
```

I'm stuck with this. my version is incomplete:

```
int printIndented(int size, String word, boolean n) {
    String spaces = ("");

    print(spaces);

    print(word);
    if(n == true)  println("");    
    else 
    if(n == false)  print("");    
    return(size);
```

Comment: I would take a look at [the for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details, but essentially, you want to loop `size` times and print that many spaces...

Comment: You're not printing spaces, you're just printing empty string `""`. Add some spaces between the quotes.

Comment: @RoyDictus I believe the homework tag has being depreciated

Comment: Give some thought you will do it....

Comment: Notice that when a boolean isn't true, is false, the second check is completely unnecessary. You can use if(n){...}else{...} instead

Comment: For many different ways to print the indentation spaces, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: i do not find any need to return int in printIndented it can be void printIndented(int size, String word, boolean newline) {..}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my version:

```
void printIndented(int size, String word, boolean n)
{
    print(StringUtils.repeat(" ", size));

    print(word);
    if(n)
       println("");    
}
```

The function, as I see it, doesn't need to return anything. Just returning the `size` parameter tells the caller nothing new.

You can find the `StringUtils` class in the *Apache Commons Lang* library. See http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html.

Without `StringUtils.repeat`, you can replace the first line by:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) print(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a homework, I will not show you a full solution, but I'll try to guide you.

You should print space `size` times, you are not doing that. Instead, you're printing `""` (Which is not a space) one time.

Tips:

- Use a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) - Print space (`" "`) `size` times (`String space = " ";` Also note that it should be named `space` instead of `spaces` since it represents only one space.
- A new line is represented as `\n` - You might also want to see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) too.
- When you check if a `boolean` is `true`, it's better to do `if(n)` instead of `if(n == true)`.
- The parenthesis around the `return` statement are redundant, you can remove them.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
String spaces = ("");
```

to

```
String spaces = " ";
```

and Make your `print(spaces)` in a loop so that it prints the spaces equlas to the integer `size`.

```
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         print(spaces);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void printIndented(int i, String s, boolean b) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        System.out.print(", ");//Comma is to see how many spaces in output
    }
    System.out.print(s);
    if(b){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("NewLine");//to see that new line was added
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops? [We don't need no stinkin' loops!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

```
public void printIndented(int size, String word, boolean n) {
    System.out.printf("%" + size + "s%s" + (n ? "%n" : ""), "", word);
}
```

* *ducks* *