# How to repeat string "n" times in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to be able to repeat a string of text "n" times:

Something like this -

```
String "X",
user input = n,
5 = n,
output: XXXXX
```

I hope this makes sense...
(Please be as specific as possible)

Comment: it is very easy to implement. what did you tried so far?

Comment: I've been trying to use a for loop but I'm not having much luck...

Comment: How does the for loop look? Also, luck has nothing to do with it. For something as basic as this, you should follow a basic tutorial, not ask a question here.

Comment: +1 I actually think that's a valid question since in other languages there is an operator that does that: perl -e "print  'X' x 5"  ->
XXXXX

Comment: Java 11 to the rescue: `String s = "X"; String newStr = s.repeat(n);`

Answer (score 26):

```
str2 = new String(new char[10]).replace("\0", "hello");
```

note: this answer was originally posted by user102008 here: [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java/4903603#4903603)

Answer (score 11):

To repeat string n number of times we have a repeat method in [Stringutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class from Apache commons.In repeat method we can give the String and number of times the string should repeat and the separator which separates the repeated strings.

Ex: `StringUtils.repeat("Hello"," ",2);`

returns "Hello Hello"

In the above example we are repeating Hello string two times with space as separator. we can give n number of times in 3 argument and any separator in second argument.

[Click here for complete example](http://java-interview-questions.com/how-to-repeat-a-string-n-number-of-times-in-java-with-single-line/)

Comment: This is my preferred solution too as it is very readable, and especially when using a separator it has its special cases taken care of

Comment: The class is actually "StringUtils" not "Stringutils"

Answer (score 6):

A simple loop will do the job:

```
int n = 10;
String in = "foo";

String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    result += in;
}
```

or for larger strings or higher values of `n`:

```
int n = 100;
String in = "foobarbaz";

// the parameter to StringBuilder is optional, but it's more optimal to tell it
// how much memory to preallocate for the string you're about to built with it.
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(n * in.length());
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    b.append(in);
}
String result = b.toString();
```

Comment: You should construct your `StringBuilder` with an argument of `n * in.length()`. In any case, +1

Comment: I have no idea how your code is related to what you're asking; also, comments are not the right place to post snippets longer than 1 line. In general, I would recommend learning Java by reading a book or tutorial. Also, it's not good practice to keep asking more and more questions after people have already answered your original question.

Comment: Again: that's actually a new question, first of all; and secondly, that's such a trivial task that if you're not able to solve that independently, you **REALLY** should read a Java book or tutorial first. (...or any other programming language for that matter)