# Duplicate string in java

Tags: java

I want to duplicate a String by a given number separated by `,`. For example:

```
int i=3;
String word = "a"; 
String result = String.duplicate(word, ',', i);

// result is: "a,a,a"
```

I know there is something like that in Ruby but I'm looking in Java. I wrote some code with a loop and then I removed the last char (which is the `,`). I wondered if there is a build-in function.

I did write my own function, I just wanted to know if there is build-in for that..

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java (but not quite)

Comment: You may also be interested in https://bitbucket.org/adamldavis/dollar/wiki/Home

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commons Lang - [StringUtils#repeat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
StringUtils.repeat("a", ",", 3);
```

Comment: True, but I wrote it before the question was rephrased and the *"lets all write how to concatenate strings" mania* started :).

Answer (score 1):

why not write a method of your own

```
public String duplicate(String word, String separator, int count) {

  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i =0; i < count; i++) {
    str.append(word);
    if (i != count - 1) {
      // append comma only for more than one words
      str.append(separator);
    }
  }

   return str.toString();
}
```

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in native Java to do this (besides actually doing it obviously):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(join("a", ",", 3));
}

public static String join(final String in, final String on, final int num) {
    if (num < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(in);
    for (int i = 1; i < num; ++i) {
        stringBuilder.append(on).append(in);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

In Guava you could do:

```
Joiner.on(',').join(Collections.nCopies(3, "a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a log (n) solution:

```
public static String join(String string, int n){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
   StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append(",");

   for (;n>0;n=n>>1){
        if (n%2==1){
           out.append(sb.toString());
        }
       sb.append(sb);
   }

   out.deleteCharAt(out.length()-1);
   return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: This actually does more work than a simple loop. There's not much you can do to make it faster. Only thing that I can come up with is counting amount of space required and preallocating the buffer before filling it