# Print a String 'X' Times (No Loop)

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to print a string 'x' times?

For example if given the string

```
String q = "*";
```

Let's say the user entered the number '4' for the amount of times that they wanted the string repeated.

The program would print:

```
****
```

Comment: You can use recursion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use recursion like this

```
private void printStar(int n){
    if(n > 0){
        System.out.print("*");
        printStar(n-1);
    }
}
```

And call the method like this initially - `printStar(4);`

Comment: println prints it on every other line!

Comment: I'd prefer a loop instead of recursive call. If ``n`` is very big you may get ``StackOverflowException`` (or is it ``Error``?)

Comment: @Toochka - OPs requirement was to "not" use any explicit loops in the code.

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of a `char[]` array of given length to build a `String`, then replace each character with `*`:

```
String repeatedStar = new String(new char[4]).replace('\0', '*');
```

Well, that would use a loop internally though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 5):

From the [Apache commons common-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29%29,%20StringUtils.repeat), use `StringUtils.repeat`:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat(q,4));
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it probably loops internally, you could use Guava's [`Strings`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html) avoiding loops in the user code:

```
System.out.println(Strings.repeat("*", 4));
```

Comment: in the background, it uses for-loop too, I guess.

Comment: I don't doubt it but useful for avoiding looping in the user code ;)

Answer (score 3):

In recursion

```
printStar(int x)
{
   if(x > 0)
   {
     System.out.print("*");
     printStar(x-1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the point is probably to use recursion, but recursion in this case is a horrible solution. Here's a solution that is more efficient (though it very likely uses a loop in `Arrays.fill`!)

```
public static void printNX(int n)
{
    char[] c = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(c, 'x');
    System.out.println(new String(c));
}
```

Of course, it's possible that `Arrays.fill` is calls into native code which is optimized to use an efficient instruction for filling the array and avoids a loop. But you never know.

I don't necessarily agree that using recursion "isn't looping"; all this is doing is thrashing the stack; the the CPU will still technically loop by continually jumping back to the top of the recursive function.