# String repeat with method

Tags: java, string

So I need to write a method which accepts one String object and one integer and repeat that string times integer.

For example: repeat("ya",3) need to display "yayaya"
I wrote down this code but it prints one under the other. Could you guys help me please?

```
public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String[] args){

     repeat("ya", 5);
  }

  public static void repeat(String str, int times){

    for(int i = 0;i < times;i++){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `System.out.println` to `System.out.print` (and add a `System.out.println();` after your loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a String 'X' Times (No Loop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455473/print-a-string-x-times-no-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing it on new line, so try using this :

```
public static void repeat(String str, int times){

    for(int i = 0;i < times;i++){
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `System.out.println` which prints what is contained followed by a new line. You want to change this to:

```
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    repeat("ya", 5);
  }

  public static void repeat(String str, int times){
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
      System.out.print(str);
    }
    // This is only if you want a new line after the repeated string prints.
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `System.out.println()` to `System.out.print()`.

Example using `println()`:

```
System.out.println("hello");// contains \n after the string
System.out.println("hello");
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
```

Example using `print()`:

```
System.out.print("hello");
System.out.print("hello");
```

Output:

```
hellohello
```

Try to understand the diference.

Your example using recursion/without loop:

```
public class Repeat {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Repeat rep = new Repeat();
        rep.repeat("hello", 10);
        System.out.println(rep.builder);    
    }


    public void repeat(String str, int times){
        if(times == 0){
            return;
        }
        builder.append(str);

        repeat(str, --times);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pgm {

  public static void main(String[] args){

     repeat("ya", 5);
  }

  public static void repeat(String str, int times){

    for(int i = 0;i < times;i++){
        System.out.print(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Avoid posting code only answers if you can. Tell the OP how your answer answers the question or what was wrong with their provided solution