# How do I replace all the letters in a string with another character using Java?

Tags: java

I want to be able to replace all the letters in a string with an underscore character.

So for example, lets say that my string is made up of the alpha characters: "Apple". How would I convert that into five underscores, because apple has five characters (letters) in it?

Comment: All characters or all letters?

Comment: You should have tried something. Show us that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `String.replaceAll()` method.

To replace all letters:

```
String originalString = "abcde1234";
String underscoreString = originalString.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","_");
```

If you meant all characters:

```
String originalString = "abcde1234";
String underscoreString = originalString .replaceAll(".", "_");
```

Comment: Change `originalString.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]+","_");` To `originalString.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","_");`, or it will only output 1 underscore

Answer (score 2):

Why not ignore the "replace" idea and simply create a new string with the same number of underscores...

```
String input = "Apple";

String output = new String(new char[input .length()]).replace("\0", "_");
//or
String output2 = StringUtils.repeat("_", input .length());
```

largely from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java).

As many others have said, `replaceAll` is probably the way to go if you don't want to include whitespace. For this you don't need the full power of regex but unless the string is absolutely huge it certainly wouldn't hurt.

```
//replaces all non-whitespace with "_"
String output3 = input.replaceAll("\S", "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        String content = "apple";
        String replaceContent = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++)
        {
            replaceContent = replaceContent + content.replaceAll("^\\p{L}+(?: \\p{L}+)*$", "_");
        }

        System.out.println(replaceContent);
```

Use [Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Regarding `\p{L}`: Refer [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

Comment: Huh? Your regex is mental

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String word="apple";

        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
            word = word.replace(word.charAt(i),'_');
        }
        System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: Why this condition?     if (word.length()== 5)

Comment: I think I missread his requirement .. I thought he only want to convert IF he only get words with five charactors

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
String str = "Apple";
str = str.replaceAll(".", "_");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: This will not have five underscores right? Only one As far as i know

Comment: @poohdedoo No you will get five underscores

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        String sample = "Apple";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(char value : sample.toCharArray())
        {
            stringBuilder.append("_");
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringToModify.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","_");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
int length = "Apple".length();
String underscores = new String(new char[length]).replace("\0", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","_");`

---

```
    String str="stackoverflow";
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        builder.append('_');
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I'll toss in an alternative:

```
String input = "Apple";
char[] newCharacters = new char[input.length()];
Arrays.fill(newCharacters, '_');
String underscores = new String(newCharacters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or here's a nice, recursive approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(underscores("Apple"));
}

public static String underscores(String input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) return "";
    else return "_" + underscores(input.substring(1));
}
```