# Does Java provide a way to repeat a string?

Tags: java, string, repeat

I have a variable:

```
String title = "titleHere";
```

How would I print the name out three times instead of writing

```
System.out.println(title);
System.out.println(title);
System.out.println(title);
```

or using a `for` loop?

For example, Ruby lets you write `title * 3` and Perl lets you write `title x 3`, so does Java have this too?

Comment: ... thanks ...I know how to use the for loop I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without it like System.out.println(title*3), but I guess not.

Comment: Totally checked the other questions you've asked, and you aren't this novice... If this were Facebook, I would ask if you've been "hacked..."

Comment: Please read the basics of programming. then you would not came through such doubts.

Comment: No doubts, just looking for an alternative way. Seeing as theres always more than way to do something, I figured I'd ask.

Comment: I see what you were asking for... That would have to have been written into the Java API, it isn't, but check my answer...

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [static] utility method that takes a string and an int.

```
public static void multiPrint(String message, int printCount) {
   for (int i = 0; i < printCount; i++) {
       System.out.println(message);
   }
}
```

I'd probably put it in a separate class and call that whenever you need the functionality...

Comment: For my purposes, this was exactly what I needed. I didn't think to put it in a method.  Thanks man.

Comment: @jdc987 Awesome, but why did you accept The Dark Knight's answer over mine. I feel like Harvey Dent... I "got the girl," but I'm dead. I guess Batman always wins in the end...

Comment: @jdc987 Also, there is a reason methods like this don't exist in API, they tend to be niche cases and simple to implement for the individual programmers that need them. I usually make a 'Utilities' class filled with tons of static methods to do the obscure things that I need depending upon the project.

Comment: @Tonithy That is exactly what I do. In fact, I create a bunch of classes with static methods, grouping like methods together (for easier reference when I want to change something). Then, I have my `Utils` class extend one which extends another, etc (creating an "extends" chain)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of for loop. Just change init condition (i=0) and loop break check (i<3)   as per your need.

```
 String title;
    title = "titleHere";


for (int =0;i<3;i++){
 System.out.println(title);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a for loop like

```
for(int i = 0; i < no_of_times; i++)
{`
    System.out.println(title);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're looking for another alternative, you could also use a while loop:

```
String title = "titleHere";

int i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    System.out.println(title);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a For Loop

```
String title;
title = "titleHere";
for(int i = 0; i < no_of_times; i++)
{
    System.out.println(title);
}
```