# How to append custom number of characters to a string?

Tags: java, string

How to add to custom position in a string variable number of custom characters not using any loops? What is the most efficient way?

```
if(s.length() < width) {  //add spaces
            n = width - s.length();
            s = (' '*n ) + s; // pseudo code
       }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please clarify the question. Perhaps you want to use a StringBuilder, but I'm not sure?

Comment: What do you mean by custom characters ? May you're looking for the `insert(int offset, CharSequence cs)` method of the StringBuilder class. `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
  sb.insert(2, "aaaa"); s = sb.toString();`

Comment: `String s = input.substring(0, x) + yourChars + input.substring(x+1);` ?!

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java help?

Comment: @EdgarBoda: It's defined at runtime how much of `yourChars` is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
String repeated = new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", yourChar);
String s = input.substring(0, x) + repeated + input.substring(x+1);
```

Where `n` is the amount of times you want the String `yourChar` repeated (which can also be longer than just one Character)

From: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java).