# how to print n number of stars without using loop or condition

Tags: java

Suppose we are giving run time value of n and we want to print the n number of stars in a single row without making use loop and/or condition. How we can do it in java?

Comment: With [tag:java-8], not the simplest though: `System.out.println(String.join("*", new String[n+1]).replace("null",""));`

Comment: @ZouZou maybe a bit cleaner: `System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(n).collect(joining()));`

Comment: @assylias That's also nice! May you could simply do: `Stream.generate(() -> "*").limit(n).forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: @ZouZou indeed! Depends on whether you need the string or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is a neat little trick you could use.

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", "*"));
```

Credit for that little snippet goes to user102008 in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java)...

Essentially you are creating a new string using a new char array with [n] indexes. When you create a new array without specifying values, default values are given. The default char is `'\0'` (the null character). So, by using `replace()` on the created string you can replace all instances of that character (the number of which you have already specified) with whatever `char`/`String` you like.

Comment: What's the point of answering by copying from a duplicate?

Comment: @s.bandara - They wanted to know and they might not have found it otherwise. Would you have rated it up if I hadn't given credit to it's  creator?

Comment: As this is likely homework related, I would downvote it either for being unhelpful to the OP or [code trolling](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/746/code-troll-rules) (outside of code golf.SE).

Comment: @MichaelT - How exactly is that code trolling? It does exactly what they ask in one line, it's concise, fairly easy to read and has little to no overheads. By the definition you just linked it is literally the opposite of code-trolling.

Comment: That you @RudiKershaw i got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to print out stars with the following code:

```
public class RecursiveStars {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        printStar(5);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param i
     *            the number of stars to print
     */
    private static void printStar(final int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.print('*');
            printStar(i - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to avoid the condition you can still use recursion but break out of the loop by triggering an ArithmeticException. (This is horrible, but does meet your requirement.)

```
public class RecursiveStars {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            printStar(5);
        } catch (final ArithmeticException e) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param i
     *            the number of stars to print
     */
    private static void printStar(final int i) {
        final int triggerException = 1 / i;
        System.out.print('*');
        printStar(i - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You include condition.

Comment: +1 for exceptional solution :D

Comment: @T8Z I've added a modified example without the condition - not sure I'd recommend it other than to prove a point.

Comment: @T8Z No need to apologise - I'd missed part of the original question.

Comment: I think recursion is another form of looping.

Comment: @user1969029 recursion and looping can both be used to solve similar problems, but they are not identical. I've not made use of any Java loop constructs.