# Any ways to find out "beautiful numbers"

Tags: java, android, numbers

A beautiful number is a number containing only one type of digit, such as these: `0`, `4`, `44`, `55555`, `3333`.

I would like to write an android app that finds out if a number is beautiful or not.

Comment: defination of beautiful = ?????

Comment: @Farhan: I think he means that's its's made out of a single type of digit.

Comment: if thats the only case, then multiple logics can be used. one would be to convert in char array, and check if all are same..

Comment: That's what I did in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check  how many digits the number has, for example the number has 5 digits(between 10000-99999 and >= 11111)

```
 if(num % 11111 == 0){
     //it is beautiful number
 }else{
     //it is not beautiful 
 }
```

This is only an example for 5 digit numbers. You can develop an algorithm for checking other num of digits. I don't know is there any algorithm created before.

Comment: In case you need algorithm for various number of digits, my answer below does just that.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean isBeautiful(int n) {
    char targetDigit = String.valueOf(n).toCharArray()[0];
    for (char currentDigit : String.valueOf(n).toCharArray()) {
        if (targetDigit != currentDigit) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Bonus (sorry for the late addition of the bonus, but here it is), here's how to get all beautifuls up to x:

```
public static List<Integer> getBeautifuls(int upTo) {
    List<Integer> beautifuls = new ArrayList<>();
    int next = 0;
    while (upTo >= next) {
        beautifuls.add(next);
        if (String.valueOf(next).toCharArray()[0] == '9') {
            next = Integer.valueOf(new String(new char[String.valueOf(next).length() + 1]).replace("\0", "1"));
        } else {
            next = next + Integer.valueOf(new String(new char[String.valueOf(next).length()]).replace("\0", "1"));
        }
    }
    return beautifuls;
}
```

Repeted string algorithm based on user102008's excellent answer on this question: [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java)

Note: Using `String`s to create `int`s is a bit hack-ish and not so fast.