# Construct a string from a repeated character

Tags: java, string

In Java I need to construct a string of `n` zeros with `n` unknown at compile time. Ideally I'd use

`String s = new String('0', n);`

But no such constructor exists. `CharSequence` doesn't seem to have a suitable constructor either. So I'm tempted to build my own loop using `StringBuilder`.

Before I do this and risk getting defenestrated by my boss, could anyone advise: is there a standard way of doing this in Java? In C++, one of the `std::string` constructors allows this.

Comment: Strings are *immutab;e* in java. So, you will have to create a new String once you append "n variable length String". StringBuilder would be the way to go.

Comment: There is no function in JRE. You need to make your own

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java#4903603)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind creating an extra string:

```
String zeros = new String(new char[n]).replace((char) 0, '0');
```

Or more explicit (and probably more efficient):

```
char[] c = new char[n];
Arrays.fill(c, '0');
String zeros = new String(c);
```

---

Performance wise, the `Arrays.fill` option seems to perform better in most situations, but especially for large strings. Using a `StringBuilder` is quite slow for large strings but efficient for small ones. Using `replace` is a nice one liner and performs ok for larger strings, but not as well as `filll`.

Micro benchmark for different values of n:

```
Benchmark                       (n)  Mode  Samples        Score         Error  Units
c.a.p.SO26504151.builder          1  avgt        3       29.452 ±       1.849  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.builder         10  avgt        3       51.641 ±      12.426  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.builder       1000  avgt        3     2681.956 ±     336.353  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.builder    1000000  avgt        3  3522995.218 ±  422579.979  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.fill             1  avgt        3       30.255 ±       0.297  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.fill            10  avgt        3       32.638 ±       7.553  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.fill          1000  avgt        3      592.459 ±      91.413  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.fill       1000000  avgt        3   706187.003 ±  152774.601  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.replace          1  avgt        3       44.366 ±       5.153  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.replace         10  avgt        3       51.778 ±       2.959  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.replace       1000  avgt        3     1385.383 ±     289.319  ns/op
c.a.p.SO26504151.replace    1000000  avgt        3  1486335.886 ± 1807239.775  ns/op
```

Comment: @TimB the first option may be, for a large n. I don't think you can easily beat the second version performance wise.

Comment: Like it. `new String(new char[n]).replace((char) 0, '0');` seems almost idiomatic. The fact that you only have `n` and `'0'` once in this is particularly nice.

Comment: I was curious about the `Arrays.fill()` method implementation. I don't know what I expected.

Comment: @assylias - Will the second one be faster than a *StringBuilder*?.

Comment: @TheLostMind see performance results: `Arrays.fill` is better as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `n` sized char array and convert it to String:

```
char[] myZeroCharArray = new char[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) myZeroCharArray[i] = '0';

String myZeroString = new String(myZeroCharArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

See StringUtils in Apache Commons Lang

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: One of the easiest way to generate a string with repeated character

Comment: but needs "yet another jar" for this one thing

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a standard JDK way, but Apache commons (almost a defacto standard), has the StringUtils.repeat() method, e.g.:

```
String s = StringUtils.repeat('x', 5); // s = "xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

or the plain old String Format

```
int n = 10;
String s = String.format("%" + n + "s", "").replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s);
```