# How do I make this code for censoring words work?

Tags: java, string

I am doing an exercise from my book but it only works partially. It works for one of the three words that I want to censor. I have no idea why it works like that. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String text = "Microsoft announced its next generation Java compiler today. It uses advanced parser and special optimizer for the Microsoft JVM.";
    String forbiddenWords = "Java,JVM,Microsoft";
    String[] words = forbiddenWords.split(",");
    String newText = "";
    for(String word: words){
        System.out.println(word);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        newText = text.replaceAll(words[i], "***");
    }
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

And this is what I get for an answer:

```
*** announced its next generation Java compiler today. It uses advanced parser and special optimizer for the *** JVM.
```

I also have to censor it with the correct amount of `*` but I don't know how. I know that I am able to get the count of `*`s by using `words[i].length` but I don't know how to utilize it.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but don't use `replaceAll` unless you're using regular expressions. Use `replace`.

Comment: You are not from Scunthorpe, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not accumulating replacements, but instead assign just the last replacement to `newText`. Instead of using `newText`, just assign the new string to the `text` variable.

```
for (String word : words) {
    text = text.replaceAll(word, "***");
}
System.out.println(text);
```

Also, as noted in a comment, be aware that [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) actually expects a regular expression, so this might fail, if the strings to be replaced contain any regular expression control characters. Instead, you should just use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which will also replace all the matching substrings.

And if you want the number of `*` to match the length of the word, you can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/1639625):

```
for (String word : words) {
    String xxx = new String(new char[word.length()]).replace("\0", "*");        
    text = text.replace(word, xxx);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
********* announced its next generation **** compiler today. It uses advanced parser and special optimizer for the ********* ***.
```

---

Speaking of regular expressions, you *could* in fact also use `replaceAll` with a regular expression covering all your forbidden words, by replacing the `,` with a `|` (provided that those words contain no regex control characters).

```
String forbiddenWords = "Java,JVM,Microsoft";
text = text.replaceAll(forbiddenWords.replace(',', '|'), "***");
```

Comment: Oh my god out of frustration I have added a new String that I don't even need. Thank you! I guess I am too tired to spot it. Do you have any idea how to assign the correct amount of *s on a certain word?

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov For repeating characters, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/1639625)

Comment: `String asterisks = ""; for(int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) tmp += "*";``text = text.replaceAll(word, asterisks);` should do it.

Comment: @Zéychin I can't get a thing from this code apart from the String declaring. What's tmp? It's not even declared anywhere.

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah but it won't work. Just figured out what it should look like but all it does is it replaces the first word with one * the second with two and the third with three.

Comment: Oops! `tmp` was most certainly supposed to be `asterisks`.

Comment: @tobias_k Well the answer seems a bit more than I can take. Looks like a char declared inside the declaration of a String. Anyways I won't try to get it it seems to work. Oh and what is \0 in the replace part.

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov Well, you can also try [any of the other techniques for repeating a character from that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/1639625). What this does is: It creates a new char-array of the wanted length, which is initially full of `null` bytes (`\0`), and then replaces those `null` bytes with the actual character.