# Java letter pyramid

Tags: java, loops

Trying to figure out how to make a pyramid that looks like this:

￼[image: Example]

15 levels and screen width is 80. I can't figure out a pattern how to print it in the most useful way.

Comment: can you post the codes if you tried something

Comment: Ah, the printing of a text triangle. One of the great unsolved problems of computing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author hasn't even made an effort.

Comment: If the OP was looking for a more of a discussion based answer then its okay, but if you didn't even try to think about it, you will hinder your ability to code. As a programmer your job is to think about how to solve issues and then apply your solutions

Answer (score 5):

**First** of all

- To post a question in SO is 
  **MANDATORY** to show [`WhatHaveYouTried`](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) first.
- Lack of effort will attract downvotes and closing flags to your question.

---

**Second**, in order to achieve your goal, *divide et impera*, so lets get started!

1. char in java are *numerical* so you can take `char c = 'a'` and do `c++` to get `b`
2. You have to increase size in 2 starting from 1
3. the space will be reduced inverse to number of chars.
4. you have to repeat the char `n` times increasing in each iteration, I've found a one-liner in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/3850595)

---

Knowing this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // get the char (point 1)
    char c = 'a';
    // iterate till 15 increasing 2 (31) - point 2)
    for (int i = 1; i < 31; i +=2) {
        // print spaces (point 3) 
        // NOTE 40 = 80/2 (screen size)
        System.out.print(new String(new char[40-i/2]).replace("\0", " "));
        // print body of pyramid (point 4)
        System.out.println(new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", c +""));
        // get next letter (point 1)
        c++;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                                    a
                                   bbb
                                  ccccc
                                 ddddddd
                                eeeeeeeee
                               fffffffffff
                              ggggggggggggg
                             hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
                            iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
                           jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
                          kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
                         lllllllllllllllllllllll
                        mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
                       nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
                      ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

[Check here a working demo](https://ideone.com/R5dxXj)

Comment: Why not one line print? `System.out.println(new String(new char[40-i/2]).replace("\0", " ") + new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", c +""));`

Comment: Just for the OP, to be clearer

Comment: Hi @Adam, as I can see in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4312153/adam-morad) you have not accepted *any* answer in *any* of your questions. As new user you must know: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. **This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.** Of course, there is no obligation to do this.