# How does one go about doing so

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Write a method called multiConcat that takes a String and an integer as parameters. Return a String made up of the string parameter concatenated with itself count time, where count is the integer. for example, if the parameters values are “ hi” and 4, the return value is “hihihihi” Return the original string if the integer parameter is less than 2.

What i have so Far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Methods_4_16 {
public static String multiConcat(int Print, String Text){
    String Msg;
    for(int i = 0; i < Print; i ++ ){

 }
    return(Msg);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Prints;
    String Texts;

    System.out.print("Enter Text:");
    Texts = Input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter amount you wanted printed:");
    Prints = Input.nextInt();

    System.out.print(multiConcat(Prints,Texts));



 }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact question you have?

Comment: How would i go about adding a string that copys the mesage

Comment: What part of your code is supposed to perform the actual concatenation?

Comment: Try `Msg += Text;` in your loop body. Also, try to learn about Java variable naming conventions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24946101/636009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few hints:

- concating strings can be done this way: `appendTo += stuffToConcat`
- repeating an operation `n` times can be done with a for-loop of this kind:

  ```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
      //do the stuff you want to repeat here
  }
  ```

Should be pretty simple to build the solution from these two parts. And just in case you get a `NullPointerException`: remember to initialize `Msg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String multiConcat(int print, String text){
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < print; i ++ ) {
        msg.append(text);
    }
    return msg.toString();
}
```

I have used StringBuilder instead of a String. To know the difference, give this a read: [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Also, I would guess you are new to Java programming. Give this link a read. It is about [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am :) and thanks i'll make sure to check it out