# Swift: Create String given length same character

Tags: swift, string

How can you create a String of a given length consisting of the same character - without using a loop?

Ie: create a String 10 characters in length where each character is an asterisk: `**********`

Similar to this [approach in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/47281): `new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", s);`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a `String` initializer for that:

> ```
> init(repeating repeatedValue: String, count: Int)
> ```
>
> **Description**
>      Creates
>   a new string representing the given string repeated the specified
>   number of times.

```
let string = String(repeating: "*", count: 10)
```