# Is it possible to use a variable and a string within the same system.out.print for a calculation?

Tags: java

```
int b1 = 0;      // This is supposed to be a running total

System.out.println("*" * (b1));
```

I know this is wrong but I was wonderingwhether there was a way to do such calculation`

I am trying to multiply the * with a variable (b1) so that it prints * depending on the variable. As the variable increases the amount of * should increase.

Comment: No. That's what loops are for.

Comment: No, there is no `*` operator in Java to print a string a repeated number of times. You have to implement this yourself with a loop.

Comment: AFAIK `java` doesn't have those fancy stuff like other dynamic languages like `ruby` etc.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/826983