# Lambda without Control Flow Statements

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

we got a task for the next week with Lambdas. 
We should write some Lambdas without Control Flow Statements. 
Example: 
We got a string and this string should repeat n-times.
Example: (string,3)-> stringstringstring.
The common problem is, that we dont know, how to catch e.g. -9 or 0.
My code looks like this:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> nAnhaengen 
    = (n, word) -> {
    Stream.iterate(word, wordAdd-> word + wordAdd).
    limit(n).
    skip(n-1).          
    forEach(element -> System.out.println(element));
    return "";
};
```

Have you an idea or tipps, how we can catch negative integers?

Thanks and Greetings Daniel

Comment: Anything wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/a/24946101/1743880?

Comment: @Tunaki we have to use lambdas with different parameters. :/

Comment: @DanielFGA so `(n, word) -> String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, word))` wouldn't work?

Comment: Well `nCopies` will throw an exception if `n` is negative. So that should be taken care of before.

Comment: The issue is, that if the integer is < 1, than we get an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: And the questions is how?

Comment: Because we shouldnt use Control Statements like if/else/?/for...

Comment: Using `Math.max(0, n)` as the argument to `nCopies` can take care of it... If you can call that "without control flow statements". And assuming you want to return an empty String if it is negative...

Comment: @Tunaki great idea! I will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IntStream.

```
int n = -1;
String word = "string";

String string = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(a -> word).reduce(String::concat).orElse("");
System.out.println(string);
```

OR

Change your code to have limit to 0 if value specified is lesser than 0

```
string = Stream.iterate(word, a -> a).limit(Math.max(0, n)).reduce(String::concat).orElse("");
System.out.println(string);
```

**Edit:**
 As @Tunaki suggested
Using Foreach and StringBuilder, as String::concat causes a lot of unnecessary immutable strings to be created.

```
String string = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(a -> word).collect(Collectors.joining())
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: `.reduce(String::concat)` will be quite slow, as it is concatenating strings which are immutable, so creating a lot of new instances of string. This specific example is referenced in the docs themselves https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for the suggestion :) Edited the answer to make use of StringBuilder.

Comment: There is a proper way to do that without `forEach`, see the linked documentation in the previous comment, and the use of `collect`. It makes sure the stream can be run in parallel without any issues (like you would encounter with `forEach` here).

Comment: @Tunaki But collect would collect the string as a list or collections in general, so it wouldn't give the concatenated output the question requested right? i.e., `stringstringstring` for `(string,3)` as input. Is there a way to use collect the result in a single string using Streams.collect?

Comment: Yes, if you use [`joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--).

Comment: @Tunaki Ahh, nice :) Didn't know we could use Joining. Will update with your solution.