# A recursive exponential function that prints 2^n asterisks, e.g. if n=3, it prints ********

Tags: java, recursion

Write the definition of a method named makePowerOfTwoStars that receives a non-negative integer n and prints a string consisting of 2^n asterisks. The method must not use a loop of any kind.

```
public static String makePowerOfTwoStars(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return "*";
    else {
        return "*" + makePowerOfTwoStars((int)(Math.pow(2,n-1) - 1)) + "*";
    }
}
```

I have been working on this for a while, and I cannot figure out the necessary algorithm to accomplish the goal.

After continuing to work on this, it seems that the method itself is a void method that does the printing itself. Thanks to Antoniossss for the working algorithm for the String-returning method. Now I get the error "void type not allowed here". I realize it makes no sense to print something from a method that returns nothing, but I don't really know how to fix it, since the program that calls the method does not print. Here is the new code, and thanks for the help.

```
public static void printPowerOfTwoStars(int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
    } else {
        System.out.print(printPowerOfTwoStars(n - 1) + printPowerOfTwoStars(n - 1));
    }
}
```

Also, I realize that the method name has changed. The program that calls the method apparently has a typo.

Comment: Can you use a stringbuilder and a for loop to create a string with n amount of asterisks?

Comment: @This_Is_Alex_ no loops are allowed.

Comment: Sorry missed the most important part

Comment: Or a non-recursive method `int n = 5;
     String output = new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", "*");
     System.out.println(output);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat close but it should be 32 stars

Comment: or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: `stars(n) : if n == 0 then result = "*"; else result = stars(n-1) + stars(n-1);`.  Just think of it: 2^n is actually 2 * 2^(n-1).  i.e. you get number of stars for `(n-1)`, and then double it

Comment: @Antoniossss Good joke

Comment: @ScaryWombat well I think that's not a joke: OP is asking how to print `2^n` stars, not n stars

Comment: @AdrianShum I would have thought that the OP would have enough java knowledge to know to replace `n` with `2^n`

Comment: @ScaryWombat that's actually my doubt :P

Comment: @AdrianShum I probably could have figured that out, but the method isn't recursive, so ultimately is not particularly helpful in this instance.

Comment: @ScaryWombat where is that joke ?

Comment: @Antoniossss My Bad, I thought you were joking. It seems that people assume that the OP does not know how to replace `int n = 5;` with `int n = 5;
  n = (int)(Math.pow(2,n-1) - 1);`

Comment: @so8857 Why my method is not recursive? It IS recursive.  The way to find stars for n is to find stars for n-1 and double it.  if n == 0, it is 1 star.  Very typical recursive method

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry mate 4:14am here, didnt get the you right.

Comment: It's marked as duplicate so I can't provide an official answer, but this works. Keep in mind though that it's VERY inefficient, but it sounds like you don't really care about that. `public static String makePowerOfTwoStars(int n) {
  if ( n == 0 ) {
   return "*";
  } else {
   return makePowerOfTwoStars( n-1 ) + makePowerOfTwoStars( n-1 );
  }
 }`

Comment: @Antoniossss I must have misunderstood what you were saying. Sry. I have updated the problem, and thanks for your help.

Comment: @voipdaddy Thanks for your help. I updated the problem.

Comment: Just remove the System.out.println from your recursive call. Instead just do two recursive calls like this: `public static void printPowerOfTwoStars(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
    } else {
        printPowerOfTwoStars(n - 1); printPowerOfTwoStars(n - 1);
    }}`

Comment: @voipdaddy Thanks so much! It works.