# Add a space between every number using loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to get a single line to output and look somewhat like this:

```
1 2  3   4    5     6      7       8        9
```

Adding another space every time the number increases.
I need to do it using for loops, with a nested for loop being preferred. 
Here's my code so far (on run it doesn't print even with the method call.)

```
public static void outputNine()
{
    for(int x=1; x<=9; x++)
    {
        for(char space= ' '; space<=9; space++)
        {
            System.out.print(x + space);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm fairly new to java so I'm not quite sure what. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `for(char space= ' '; space<=9; space++)` will never execute: `space <= 9` is immediately false, because `' ' == 32`.

Comment: @shmosel I tried your suggestion and received an output but got this "333435363738394041"

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize `space` only once, then print the numbers, and for every number, print the spaces:

```
char space = ' ';
for(int x=1; x<=9; x++)
{
    System.out.print(x);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(space);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is using the ASCII value of `' '`, which isn't what you want. You just need to count up to the current `x`. Replace your inner loop with this:

```
System.out.print(x);
for (int s = 0; s < x; s++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to increment a char, which doesn't make sense. You want `space` to be a number equivalent to the number of spaces you need.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop.

Refer: [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d%s", i, new String(new char[i]).replace('\0', ' '));
}
```

Output

`1 2  3   4    5     6      7       8        9`

Or more optimally,

```
int n = 9;
char[] spaces =new char[n];
Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    out.print(i);
    out.write(spaces, 0, i);
}
out.flush();
```

Comment: It'd be better if you built the string once, as big as you need it to be. You can then use the `print(String, int, int)` overload to print part of the string.

Comment: I meant [`PrintWriter.write(char[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write(char[],%20int,%20int)). Always forget where that is.

Comment: @AndyTurner Was about to say, that method call doesn't sound familar

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz not just constructor calls, `replace("\0", " ")` is going to be very slow because it uses regex. `replace('\0', ' ')` would be much better.

Comment: @AndyTurner Better?

Comment: Create all the objects! You create 4 objects when 1 will do. Why not `char[] spaces = new char[n]; Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line as composed of 9 parts of the same structure: `x-1` spaces followed by `x`, where `x` change from 1 to 9.

```
/*
0 space + "1"
1 space + "2"
2 spaces + "3"
...
*/

int n = 9;
for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    // Output x - 1 spaces
    for (int i = 0; i < x - 1; i++) System.out.append(' ');
    // Followed by x
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

One good thing about this approach is you don't have trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my simple solution:)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(i);
        }

    }

}
```