# How can I repeat a JSONArray result of a json.getString?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, getjson

I have a problem with repeating a JSONArray.
I can't repeat this string:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    String.repeat("firstname", 3);
                    Data=Data+""+  json.getString("firstname");
                    Data=Data+""+  json.getString("remark");
                    Data=Data+""+  json.getString("s_start");
                    Data=Data+""+  json.getString("department");

                }
```

How should I repeat this line?

Comment: There is no such method like String.repeat();

Comment: this is pretty much your question then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String repeat = StringUtils.repeat(string_you_want_to_repeat, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `StringUtil.repeat("firstname",3)` not `String.repeat("firstname",3)`.

[Here is the link for official documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-java.lang.String-int-)