# how to use java lambdas to append n number of chars to a string?

Tags: java, lambda

basically I'd like to see if there is a compact lambda way of doing this:

```
int n = ...
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  s += 'a';
}
```

The start is easy, then I'm lost:

```
IntStream.range(0, n). ??
```

Comment: [`String s = StringUtils.repeat('a', n);`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-char-int-)

Comment: This is not a dupe of "how to repeat a string"; this asks for a lambda equivalent of this code

Comment: @Bohemian And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27690536/438154) answer there provides that. Looks very much like yours.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hmmm, it does. I interpret the actual code here as being secondary to the main question, which is IMHO "how to do implement this loop as a stream". So, I don't think the *question* is the same, but when it's closed as a dupe the message reads "This question already has an answer here...", which is true. It's a topic for meta, but fine let's close it then

Answer (score 5):

This is better:

```
String s = Stream.generate(() -> "a").limit(n).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: True, this one is much sleeker

Comment: You can even eliminate the lambda by using `Stream.generate("a"::toString)`, making this a pure non-lambda Stream solution. Although question specifically asks for a *lambda* version of the code, I would postulate that might be a "typo", and that OP really wanted a *Stream* version.

Answer (score 2):

It is very straightforward;

```
int n = 20;
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, n).boxed().map(i -> "a").collect(Collectors.joining()));
```

Prints out;

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

You have to do `boxed()` to switch to a `Integer` stream, then just map each number to a `"a"` String, which will transform your stream of `1,2,3,4...` to `a,a,a,a,a...` and finally join them.

Answer (score 0):

Why use stream/lambda for this? Less efficient.

If you want a one-liner, try this instead:

```
String s = new String(new char[n]).replace('\0', 'a');
```

Comment: Well, we'd have to profile to be sure - for small values of `n` you are certainly right, but this approach creates 3 arrays of size `n` (of which two are very short lived - perhaps they can be eliminated by optimization?)

Comment: Another appoach would be filling the array in place with [Arrays.fill()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-char:A-char-) before passing it to the String constructor - would avoid one copy.

Comment: @Hulk True, `Arrays.fill()` is what I would usually use, since that is truly the best way, but you seemed to be looking for a one-liner.

Comment: that's pretty clever.   The reason for lambdas was just to see how it would be done using lambdas.  nothing more.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asked for a lambda