# Java Substring Iteration Issue

Tags: java, string, substring

I am working on a simple program that needs to return 3 times a certain substring. For example, a call such as makeThreeSubstr("hello",0,2) should return "hehehe". I have the code ready to return "he", but I don't know an simple way to output the substring three times in a row. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Main {
 public static String makeThreeSubstr (String word, int startIndex, int endIndex)
 {
  return (word.substring(startIndex, endIndex));

 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(makeThreeSubstr("hello",0,2)); //should be hehehe
    System.out.println(makeThreeSubstr("shenanigans",3,7)); //should be naninaninani
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s = word.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
return s + s + s;
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer I was looking for. For this specific problem, this solution works perfectly and is less cluttered than a loop.

Comment: Have a look at the link to the duplicate marked answer too. It has a similar question and users have explained it in a lot of different ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java/4903603#4903603)

```
String  repeated = new String(new char[3]).replace("\0", word.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
return repeated;
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: it would be helpful if you at least explained why. We're all just trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way to do it is:

```
public static String makeThreeSubstr (String word, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
  String substring = word.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  return substring + substring + substring;
}
```