# Adding 1-5 Letters to a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want my String in Java to end up being a multiple of 5 by adding X's to it:

Example 1:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJK" // length 11
```

I want to add 4 "X" to the end:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKXXXX" // length 15
```

Example 2:

```
"ABCDEFGHI" // length 9
```

I want to add 1 "X" to the end

```
"ABCDEFGHIX" // length 10
```

How can I do this? Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Yes I did code some I just forgot to put it in my question

```
int myInitialAmountOfX = myString.length() % 5;
System.out.println(myInitialAmountOfX);
int myTotalAmountOfX = 5 - myInitialAmountOfX;
```

Was just confused on how to append.

Comment: What exactly is your problem: calculating the number of `X`s or appending them?

Comment: Please post the code you have written until now. SO is not for writing complete code for you!

Comment: This smells like homework, and as others have pointed out you need to at least make an attempt before someone will be very willing to help. To point you in the right direction, consider that `5 - (length(input) % 5)` will tell you how many to append, after that you just need to figure out the logic for padding, which could be done in a few ways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @PM77-1 appending them, I know I can use modulus

Comment: You can append one `X` at a time in a loop.  If you already know `StringBuilder` class you might want to use it.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: @PM77-1 That's right I completely forgot, no this isn't homework everyone and I forgot to attach some code.

Comment: Indeed, as noted by YCF_L, this Question seems to be a duplicate of: [Simple way to repeat a String in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/642706). Some Answers there are clever, such as using [`Collections.nCopies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out the number of characters, that need to be appended, you can use

`(5-(s.length()%5))` I hope this is self explanatory.

And for appending a simple for loop, would do

```
for(int i=1;i<=j;i++){
    s+="X";
}
```

However, for larger Strings, you might want to prefer [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: You can also use `new String(new char[j]).replace("\0", "X");` for a nice one liner. Found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903603/5817001).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
String input = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

while ( input.length() % 5 != 0 )
    input += "X";
```

Comment: Why do you need `l`?

Comment: `Something like :` just an indication to user, yes I can just use `input.length()`

Answer (score -2):

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class PadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String str = "Pad Me";
        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Original:", str);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Left Padded:", StringUtils.leftPad(str, 10));
        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Right Padded:", StringUtils.rightPad(str, 10));
        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Centered:", StringUtils.center(str, 10));

        System.out.println();

        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Left Padded:", StringUtils.leftPad(str, 10, "*"));
        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Right Padded:", StringUtils.rightPad(str, 10, "*"));
        System.out.printf("%-15s[%s]\n", "Centered:", StringUtils.center(str, 10, "*"));

    }

}
```

The output from executing PadTest is shown below.
Results

```
Original:      [Pad Me]

Left Padded:   [    Pad Me]
Right Padded:  [Pad Me    ]
Centered:      [  Pad Me  ]

Left Padded:   [****Pad Me]
Right Padded:  [Pad Me****]
Centered:      [**Pad Me**]
```

Font: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-pad-a-string-with-spaces-or-other-characters.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: how does this answer the question above?

Comment: @JoeC Sharing information cant be unhelpful. I would have done the same way

Comment: @user7185318 I would argue that an answer like this is unhelpful because the asker can simply copy-and-paste it into whatever they're doing without any need to understand what is going on.  If this is a homework assignment (as I suspect it is), it deprives the asker of the opportunity to improve problem-solving skills that the said assignment is meant to provide.

Comment: @JoeC exactly! Have to educate users of SO

Comment: @JoeC Hi Joe! I just forgot about the StringBuilder class! I added my code where I knew about the modulus, next time I will be sure to include more code so that you don't suspect I know nothing.