# Java Regex Match and Replace matched group with characters of same length

Tags: java, regex, mask

So I want to match credit card numbers and mask them in 6*4 format. So that only first 6 and last 4 characters will be visible. The characters between will be '*'. I tried to figure it out with a MASK like;

```
private static final String MASK = "$1***$3";
matcher.replaceAll(MASK);
```

But could not find out the way to give me back equal length of stars in the middle as the group $2.

Then I implemented the below code and it works. 
But what i want to ask if there is a shorter or easier way to do this. Anyone knows it?

```
private static final String HIDING_MASK = "**********";
private static final String REGEX = "\\b([0-9]{6})([0-9]{3,9})([0-9]{4})\\b";
private static final int groupToReplace = 2;

private String formatMessage(String message) throws NotMatchedException {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(message);

    if (!m.find()) throw new NotMatchedException();
    else {
        StringBuilder maskedMessage = new StringBuilder(message);
        do {
            maskedMessage.replace(m.start(groupToReplace), m.end(groupToReplace), 
                    HIDING_MASK.substring(0, (m.end(groupToReplace) - m.start(groupToReplace))));

        } while(m.find(m.end()));

        return maskedMessage.toString();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is an **example** message to process.
"2017.08.26 20:51 [Thread-Name] [Class-Name] [MethodName] Credit card holder 12345678901234567 02/2022 123 ........."

Comment: Why use a regex for this?  `String masked = num.substring(0,6) + "******" + num.substring(12,16)`

Comment: If you really need a regex solution, then have a look at `Pattern#appendReplacement`

Comment: @slim Because I don't know what is and how many credit card numbers(if there is) in the string

Comment: Ah, hold on, are you talking about using this to find and replace numbers in a long string containing arbitrary text with credit card numbers within? If so you should edit the question to explain that -- give an example input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply with this code:

```
str.replaceAll( "(?<=\\d{6})\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*" );
```

Comment: Does what OP asked. It's inefficient, but in exchange you get unreadability ;)

Comment: It is close but it does not. My maximum card number is 19 digits.So can you edit it not to work if number is greater than 19 digits?

Comment: `if(str.length() < 19)`?

Comment: @kerberos84 Do a `if( str.matches( ".*\\b\\d{13,19}\\b.*" ) )` before

Comment: It still matches for "12345678901234567890"  which is 20 digit?

Comment: Not really, please make sure you copy the exact statement from the comment.

Comment: hi yes you are right. I mark this answer as acepted because this was written before the other answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String formatMessage(String message) throws NotMatchedException { 
    if (message.matches(".*\\b\\d{13,19}\\b.*")) {
        return message.replaceAll("(?:[.\\b]*)(?<=\\d{6})\\d(?=\\d{4})(?:[.\\b]*)", "*");
    } else {
        throw new NotMatchedException() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would be easy if the `message` contains the credit-card number only as a substring.

Comment: I am afraid you didn't understand my question. Credit card numbers are NOT always 16 digits. In my case I am looking for 13 to 19 digit cards.

Comment: Thx but I already implemented a similar approach as you can see in my question. I am interested in doing this in a simpler way similar to ALI's answer.

Comment: The replace all was also added to my answer

Comment: hi your answer is still not a solution for this. I don't know what is in the 'message'. It is not consisting of a pure credit card number. An example message: "2017.08.26 20:51 [Thread-Name] [Class-Name] [MethodName] Credit card holder 12345678901234567 02/2022 123 ........." and so on. Hence I can't just check the length of the message as your answer suggest. But thx anyway.

Comment: You can't expect an answer to part of a question you didn't include in your OP. I'll edit my answer

Comment: hi, i thought it is self explanotary from the code i wrote. but anywat my fault so i added the example to the question. thanks.

Comment: There were some typos in my last. These have been addressed

Comment: hi @anomeric i get this exception; `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 6
(?:[.\b]*)(?<=\d{6})\d(?=\d{4})(?:[.\b]*)
      ^ `  I changed the both `\\b` in the `replaceAll` mask to `\b` and now it does what i asked. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Readable but uncool.

```
String in = "1234561231234";
String mask = in
    .replaceFirst("^\\d{6}(\\d+)\\d{4}$", "$1")
    .replaceAll("\\d", "\\*");
String out = in
    .replaceFirst("^(\\d{6})\\d+(\\d{4})$", "$1" + mask + "$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if your text contains multiple credit-card numbers with variable lengths:

```
str.replaceAll( "\\b(\\d{13,19})\\b", "\u0000$1\u0000" )
   .replaceAll( "(?<=\\d{6})(?<=\u0000\\d{6,14})\\d(?=\\d{4,12}\u0000)(?=\\d{4})", "*" )
   .replaceAll( "\u0000([\\d*]+)\u0000", "$1" );
```

Not really readable, though, but it's all in one go.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution for a 16 char "number":

```
 String masked = num.substring(0,6) + "******" + num.substring(12,16);
```

For a string of arbitrary length ( >10 ):

```
 String masked = num.substring(0,6) 
               + stars(num.length() - 10) 
               + num.substring(num.length() - 6);
```

... where `stars(int n)` returns a `String` of `n` stars. See [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java) -- or if you don't mind a limit of 9 stars, `"*********".substring(0,n)`

Answer (score -1):

Use a `StringBuffer` and overwrite the desired characters:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(num);
for(int i=4; i< buf.length() - 6) {
    buf.setCharAt(i, '*');
}
return buf.toString();
```

You could also use `buf.replace(int start, int end, String str)`