# Print a variable a n number of times in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, jakarta-ee

My project is to show lines with cardinals, from an initial number and
then varying this number to another number entered.
It starts by asking for a initial number of cardinals (the output must be "###" the number of times asked) and then ask for the final number of cardinals to add. So case, click here 5 initial cardinals and add 3, the program must show a line with 5, another with 6, another with 7 and another with 8 cardinals.
How do I add the cardinals? With if-else?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P02Cardinais {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number inicial of cardinals: ");
        int numCardinais = keyboard.nextInt();  
        System.out.println("Enter the number of cardinals to add: ");
        int numCardinaisAdd = keyboard.nextInt();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numCardinais; i++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        } System.out.print(" - " + numCardinais);

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Example of the output

```
(number inicial - 2 ; number to add - 3)
## - 2
### - 3
#### - 4
##### - 5
```

Comment: What are the cardinals? Are they the `"#"` character?

Comment: Yes it is. Cardinals #

Comment: so the example output given here is the expected output or it is the generated output?

Comment: is only a example. the output depends of the numbers introduced

Comment: do it one step at a time. Start writing the code that prints the initial string. You can then try to find an efficient way to add the other characters. You can start from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: I did that already.

Comment: I do not see it in the code you posted

Comment: That prints the number inicial of cardinals... How do I add successively the other number introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 loops

- one for the number of lines from initial to initial+add
- one for the number of # which has to be the index of first loop (limo of `j` is `i`)

```
for (int i = numCardinais; i <= numCardinais+numCardinaisAdd; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
        System.out.print("#");
    } 
    System.out.println(" - " + i); // new line and index
}
```