# How to construct string like new String('A', 30) in Java

Tags: java

I'm studying Java recently.

Is there any way to make a string from char with N-times?

C#: `string str = new string('A', 30);`

Java: ???

please help me. Thank you

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to repeat a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of java are you using?

If **Java 8**

```
String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, s));
```

If **Java 11**

```
"abc".repeat(12);
```

Comment: Thats a cool j8 solution, didn't know of that!

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm using Java8 and solved as     
'String str = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(30,"A"));'

Comment: @JaeChulKim if it works, please accept the answer (hit the tick button).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it using Java 8 Streams.

```java
        String aNTimes = IntStream.range(0, 30)
                .mapToObj(index -> "A")
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```