# how do I multiply an integer input with a string in java and print it on one line?

Tags: java, string, printing, integer

I have to make a program where I calculate things and then print it all in one line. But this output also includes max. 5 stars (*****; stars are supposed to be outlined right). So I give my inputs for the calculation, the amount of stars I want and this is for example supposed to be the result:

(50,  ***, 60, 20)

for example
int a = 5
String s = "*"

Can I do

a * s as result (*****)

Am I supposed to use a for loop here, is there a way to multiply an integer with a string and print it on one line?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

---

If you need up to only 5 stars, [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) can be used:

```
"*****".substring(0, a)
```

(returns a sub-string beginning at index 0 up to index `a-1`, that is, of length `a`). Only works if there is a given/known (small) maximum number of characters.

---

probably not faster than previous, but easier to understand (and works for more *complicated* string patterns); use [`repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))<sup>1</sup>:

```
"*".repeat(5)
```

which repeats (multiplies) the given string a number of times.

<sup>1: available since Java 11</sup>