# Regular expression to replace first 4 characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Regular Expression that replaces the first 4 characters of a string with `*`s

For example, for the `123456` input, the expected output is `****56`.

If the input length is less than 4 then return only `*`s.

For example, if the input is `123`, the return value must be  `***`.

Comment: But why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: With regex you could check for not more than x char before: [`(?<!.{4}).` and replace with `*`](https://regex101.com/r/VIOQuX/1)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the selected answer @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @bobblebubble, unless you can explain why regular expressions are key part of your question, or some other way it's meaningfully different, it _is_ a duplicate. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution using [`String#repeat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) available as of [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11). Regex is not needed.

```
static String hideFirst(String string, int size) {
    return size < string.length() ?                     // if string is longer than size
            "*".repeat(size) + string.substring(size) : // ... replace the part
            "*".repeat(string.length());                // ... or replace the whole
}
```

```
String s1 = hideFirst("123456789", 4);    // ****56789
String s2 = hideFirst("12345", 4);        // ****5
String s3 = hideFirst("1234", 4);         // ****
String s4 = hideFirst("123", 4);          // ***
String s5 = hideFirst("", 4);             // (empty string)
```

- You might want to pass the asterisk (or any) character to the method for more control
- You might want to handle `null` (return `null` / throw the NPE / throw a custom exception...)
- For lower versions of Java, you need [a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1235179/3764965) for the String repetition.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below regex to catch the first up to 4 characters.

```
(.{0,4})(.*)
```

Now, you can use Pattern, Matcher, and String classes to reach what you want.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.{0,4})(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("123456");

if (matcher.matches()) {
    String masked = matcher.group(1).replaceAll(".", "*");
    String result = matcher.replaceFirst(masked + "$2");

    System.out.println(result);
    // 123456 -> ****56
    // 123 -> ***
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```java
String masked = string.replaceAll("(?<=^.{0,3}).", "*");
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/nC4kj2/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{0,3}                   any character except \n (between 0 and 3
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .                        any character except \n
```