# Replace a part of substring with a string that is repeated

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to essentially replace part of substring that contains the `"abc"` with the `*`s. I want to do this using java8 (`repeat()` does not exist in java8).

```
String s = "abcdefgh"; 
String word1 = "abc";  
s = s.replaceAll(word1,"*"*word1.length());
```

output should be:

```
s = "***defgh"
```

Comment: You can build the replacement using a loop.

Comment: how would that work because it still just replaces with only one star

Comment: @dsknjksad not if you use a loop to generate multiple `*`s which is what Chaosfire suggested.

Comment: Check [how to repeat a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this for a form of text-censoring? Because users can quickly and easily `4bc` to get around these types of filters, and other solutions exist.

Comment: @Rogue indeed, like `аbc` which does not match `abc`.

Comment: If you don't have the `repeat()` method available to you then perhaps use the [String.join()](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/string/string_join.php) method: `s = s.replace(word1, String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(word1.length(), "*")));`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
String s = "abcdefgh";
String word1 = "abc";

String replace = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
    replace += "*";
}

s = s.replaceAll(word1,replace);
System.out.println(s);
```

gives:

```
***defgh
```

Comment: when i do the replace wth the *, it seems to say dangling meta character '*' near index 0.