# How to print character repeatedly using specifier instead of loop in java?

Tags: java, format-specifiers

I want to print a char '=' repeatedly where I give the no. of times the asterisk should be repeated.

Example: count = 20 and I want to print ==================== using printf() and format specifiers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to repeat a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235179/simple-way-to-repeat-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `String#repeat`

Simply append a string generated by [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method, in Java 11+.

```
String result = "=".repeat( 20 ) ;
```

> ====================