# Help in padding numerical strings

Tags: objective-c, string, string-formatting

I am trying to generate a numerical string by padding the number with zeroes to the left.

0 would become 00000
1  would become 00001
10  would become 00010

I want to create five character `NSString` by padding the number with zeroes.

I read this [Create NSString by repeating another string a given number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260945/create-nsstring-by-repeating-another-string-a-given-number-of-times) but the output is an `NSMutableString`.

How can I implement this algorithm with the output as an `NSString`?

Best regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this by calling

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", [theNumber intValue]];
```

where `theNumber` is the `NSString` containing the number you want to format.

For further reading, you may want to look at [Apple's string formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943) or the [Wikipedia entry for printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf).

Comment: it's  `@"%05d"` not a `"%5d"`.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks, you'd think I would remember something like that by now.

Comment: I have nsstring not an integer that @"10" or @"1"

Comment: `0` is still missing before `5d` - this expression is not of much use to OP without it ;). Anyway he want to make it from string, not a number.

Comment: @Ali, I've edited it to work with an NSString as opposed to an int.  @hoha, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One quick & simple way to do it:

```
unsigned int num = 10;  // example value
NSString *immutable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5u", num];
```

If you actually really want to use the long-winded approach from the example you read, you can send a “copy” message to a mutable string to get an immutable copy. This holds for all mutable types.

Comment: I have nsstring not an integer that @"10" or @"1"