# How can I add a zero to the left of a 1 digit integer in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, digits

How can I add a zero to the left of a 1 digit integer ?
Is there any objective C function to perform this?
I am needing this so I can have only one NSDateFormat @"ddMMyyyy" thanks

I want to add a zero to the left of an integer which is less than 10, I don't want to use an if statement.
Is there any function or way to achieve this?

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want to prepend a '0' to the string representation of an integer? (e.g. (int) 1 => "01") ?

Comment: Similar to [Format string, integer with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985170/format-string-integer-with-leading-zeros).

Comment: also thank u, my question was answered correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Padding string to left with objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964322/padding-string-to-left-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the string format specifier `%02d` and any single digit integer will be padded with a zero in a string.

Comment: yes. if you use a variable 9 it will be "09" and if it is 19 then the output will be "19".

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatters to add padding to your integer value as shown here: [Help in padding numerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358702/help-in-padding-numerical-strings)